# Would like to redirect a user if the errors tag in the javascript is empty

Tags: php, javascript, validation, redirect

I am trying to redirect a user if the #errors are empty to another page. How can i go around doing that cheers! Ive tried creating an if statement but failed badly.

```
      $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#signup').validate({
                rules:{

                    first_name:"required",
                    last_name:"required",

                    email:{
                    required:true,
                    email:true
                    },

                    username:{
                    required:true,
                    minlength:6,
                    maxlength:25
                    },

                    password:{
                    required:true,
                    minlength: 8
                    },

                    password_again:{
                    required:true,
                    equalTo:"#password"
                    },


                  },  

       submitHandler: function(form) {
          $.post('process.php',$('#signup').serialize(), function(data){
              $('#errors').html(data);
            if ($('#errors').load('page2.html #errors').length === 0){
            window.location.href = "redirect.html";
        }


     });



                    }




     });

  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could explore a while loop. THere could also be other areas in your database which has created the issue.

Answer (score 0):

use error number in ur php code. for example after submit return -1 for empty error.

Comment: Error number what you mean by that mate?